# Concatenate different data type objects to return a string

Tags: c#

I currently have a Person class, which has;

```
private String name;
private Boolean glasses; 
private char gender;
```

The class will also return a sentence made up of the above variables which will be similar to the below:

"Jessica *does not have* glasses, and is a *female*".

The issue is that this sentence will be passed to the main program and would display "Jessica *true* glasses, and is a *f*", what would be the right approach to tackle this? (modify the data in the Person class).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to format a string using the person class (there is no need to change your data model).  The person object can have a function that constructs the sentence.

```
public string GetSentence()
{
    return string.Format("{0} does {1}have glasses, and is {2}", name, glasses ? "" : "not ", gender == 'm' ? "male" : "female");
}
```

Then you can call the function on your person object.

```
var somePerson = new Person("Jack", false, 'm');
var sentence = somePerson.GetSentence();

Console.WriteLine(sentence);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [conditional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) to do that in a compact form. This expression:

```
glasses ? "does" : "does not"
```

returns `does` if glasses is true, and `does not` if glasses is false.

So you might do something like this:

```
public string ConvertToString()
{
    return $"{name} {glasses ? "does" : "does not"} have glasses, and is a {c == 'm' ? "male" : "female"}";
}
```

And to print the string:
`Console.WriteLine(person.ConvertToString());`

The `$` sign I used in this example is for [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated), which is a shorter way to concatenate strings (instead of writing "aa" + "bb" + "cc")